# Position sticky not working correctly on my fixed sidebar element?

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I have the following simple markup, which includes a sidebar and main content. I can add additional elements but cannot remove existing ones (using library). I want to update the code so that page can be scrolled normally, but the sidebar content remaining fixed (while the right content scrolls).

I've added the obvious classes of sticky and top, but it still does not work as expected, can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```css
.sui-layout-body__inner {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sui-layout-sidebar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 376px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.sui-layout-main {
  width: 74.25%;
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sui-layout-body__inner">
  <div class="sui-layout-sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Sidebar element 1</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 2</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 3</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 4</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 5</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 6</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 7</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sui-layout-main">
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a height for sticky container

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `align-self: flex-start` to the sidebar

```css
.sui-layout-body__inner {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sui-layout-sidebar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 376px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
align-self: flex-start;
}

.sui-layout-main {
  width: 74.25%;
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sui-layout-body__inner">
  <div class="sui-layout-sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Sidebar element 1</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 2</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 3</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 4</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 5</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 6</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 7</li>
      <li>Sidebar element 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sui-layout-main">
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```